# Convergence bound for zero-order optimization method

Tags: computational-complexity, na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to understand the error bound for a particular zero-order optimization method: (stochastic) difference method.

To solve an nonsmooth optimization problem $min_x G(x)$ where $G$ is only a continuous function using stochastic difference descent method, that is, we use difference of function values with step size $\rho$ to replace gradient in ordinary stochastic gradient descent method. Let $x_0$ be the initial point and $x_k$ be the $k$-th point such that
\begin{equation}
x_k = x_{k-1} - \alpha \Delta_\rho G(x) |_{x=x_{k-1}}
\end{equation}
$\alpha$ is the learning rate and $\Delta_\rho G(x):= (G(x+\rho) - G(x))/\rho$ or $\Delta_\rho G(x):= (G(x+\rho) + G(x-\rho) - 2G(x)) / 2\rho$, where $\rho$ may depend on $t$ or just a constant.

Analogous to the well established bound for stochastic gradient method, is there any similar upper bound on the quantity:
$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - x_0|$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - x_0|^2$?
for this zero-order optimization problem?

Or is there any reference?